# автоматические растягивание формулы с запросом

Tags: запрос, google-spreadsheet

Есть таблица Склад. Она постоянно заполняется.
Есть таблица Наличие. Туда добавляются товары, которые находятся в наличии. Заполняю таблицу наличие через QUERY.
Сначала заполняю столбец F товарами, которые находятся в наличии.
Далее заполняю столбцы с размерами.

`=QUERY(A4:D9; "select A where D='В наличии'") - запрос для наличия`

`=QUERY(A4:D9; "select C where (A='"&F4&"' and B='XXL')") - запрос для размера`

Количество товаров в наличии постоянно меняется, как сделать автоматические растягивание формулы с запросом для размера в зависимости от наличия?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15W0uUucBhUcoFycaxd54ZMFPFUoOZYjdboCv00nrtdc/edit?usp=sharing - ссылка на таблицу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При добавлении записей через форму происходит вставка строк. Я делал с запасом через формулы с динамическими ссылками (поскольку обычные даже с $ сдвигаются при вставке строк), но может быть есть решение лучше.